# Show that partial sums of this sin series are bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hi I need to show that(if it's true) is bounded.

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=2}^{n} sin(k+\frac{1}{k})
\end{equation}

I've tried using  Euler's formula but no avail.

Comment: Isn't it bounded by $n-2+1$?

Comment: @JohnDouma you're right. Is this serie convergent when *n* goes to infinity?

Comment: @johnDouma How can I show this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denoting $ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}\right),\ S_{n}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\,k}} $, and considering the convention $ S_{0}=0 \cdot $

We know that $ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}\right),\ S_{n}=\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}}\frac{1-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\,n}}{1-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}}} $, meaning $ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^{*}\right),\ \left|S_{n}\right|=\frac{\left|1-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\,n}\right|}{\left|1-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}}\right|}\leq\frac{2}{\left|1-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}}\right|}=M\cdot $

Let $ n $ be a positive integer greater than $ 1 \cdot $

\begin{aligned} \sum_{k=1}^{n}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\left(k+\frac{1}{k}\right)}}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{1}{k}}\left(S_{k}-S_{k-1}\right)} \\ &=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{1}{k}}S_{k}}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{1}{k+1}}S_{k}}\\ &=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\left(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{1}{k}}-\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{1}{k+1}}\right)S_{k}}+\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{1}{n}}S_{n}\\ \sum_{k=1}^{n}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\left(k+\frac{1}{k}\right)}}&=2\mathrm{i}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{2k+1}{2k\left(k+1\right)}}\sin{\left(\frac{1}{2k\left(k+1\right)}\right)}S_{k}}+\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{1}{n}}S_{n}\end{aligned}

Meaning, \begin{aligned} \left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\left(k+\frac{1}{k}\right)}}\right|&=\left|2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{2k+1}{2k\left(k+1\right)}}\sin{\left(\frac{1}{2k\left(k+1\right)}\right)}S_{k}}+\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\frac{1}{n}}S_{n}\right|\\&\leq 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\left|\sin{\left(\frac{1}{2k\left(k+1\right)}\right)}\right|\left|S_{k}\right|}+\left|S_{n}\right| \end{aligned}

Using the fact that $ \left(\forall k\in\mathbb{N}^{*}\right),\ \left|\sin{\left(\frac{1}{2k\left(k+1\right)}\right)}\right|\leq\frac{1}{2k\left(k+1\right)} $, and that $ \left(\forall k\in\mathbb{N}^{*}\right),\ \left|S_{k}\right|\leq M $, we get : $$ \left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\left(k+\frac{1}{k}\right)}}\right|\leq M\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{1}{k\left(k+1\right)}}+M=M\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)+M\leq 2M $$

If $ z\in\mathbb{C}^{*} $, since $ \mathcal{Im}\left(z\right)=\frac{z^{2}-\left|z\right|^{2}}{2z\,\mathrm{i}} $, we have $ \left|\mathcal{Im}\left(z\right)\right|\leq\left|z\right| $, which means : $$ \left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\sin{\left(k+\frac{1}{k}\right)}}\right|=\left|\mathcal{Im}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\left(k+\frac{1}{k}\right)}}\right)\right|\leq\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\left(k+\frac{1}{k}\right)}}\right|\leq 2M $$